# Calling other facetime emails in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, facetime

I would like to call other facetime numbers, but these are emails and not numbers. How do I do it?

For numbers, I know what to use.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"facetime://+123456789"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

But for emails, how do i change it. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"facetime://email@example.com"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

These are the options

```
@"facetime://appleId"             // For apple id
@"facetime://email@example.com"   // For email id
@"facetime://5558675309"          // For phone number
```

Comment: @lakesh not much awesome as I searched it on goole with correct keywords.. These are called url schemes so on google if you search `facetime url scheme` you will find the answer within top 3 sites. I could have shared the link but giving links to an external blogs in answer is not recommended in SO. Anyways thanks for upvote and accept

Comment: It's all right.. No one know nothings initially. Hope you will fine other application schemes. :)